# Element disappears after being applied perspective() function with positive argument

Tags: css, css-transforms

I am reading the 8th chapter of CSS: The Definitive Guide, 4th Edition.
There is such snippet in the book:

```css
div#inner {
  transform: perspective(750px) translateZ(60px) rotateX(45deg);
}
```

```html
<div id="outer">
  outer
  <div id="inner">inner</div>
</div>
```

The div with #inner disappears from my chrome browser.
After adjusting the argument value of perspective function and setting it to 0, I can see `inner` text on the page with some rotation effect.

Do you know why? I tried this page in safari, problem still.

Comment: Which version of Chrome? Which OS? I see that inner is half cut but I can see it though.

Comment: Version of Chrome is 56.0.2924.87(64-bit) and macOS is Sierra 10.12.3. It is strange that if add `margin-left` to `body`, I can see `inner`. With the margin grows, ie. 1200px, `inner` will be almost completely under `outer`. Is it about some space awareness?

Comment: @sabithpocker I found that `translateZ()` without `transform-style: preserve-3d` will shift the element to the left with argument growing.

Comment: I don't see it disappear in Mac Chrome, atleast not the inner in this example. Are you using `perspective` on body as well? Try using only one perspective in page. Start with 2000 - 5000px and then adjust to fit your need.

Comment: Nope, nothing special applied on body. Then inner is not visible on the page. With margin on body, inner is visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The perspective origin is in the center of the element by default.

Since it is a block element, this center is way to the right of the text part of the element, and so it results in a left movement - that can take it behind the left border of the page in some resolutions.

See how it changes when the element width is lower:

```css
div#inner {
  background-color: lightblue;
  transform: perspective(750px) translateZ(60px) rotateX(45deg);
}
```

```html
<div id="outer">
  outer
  <div id="inner">inner</div>
</div>
```

```css
div#inner {
  width: 70px;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  transform: perspective(750px) translateZ(60px) rotateX(45deg);
}
```

```html
<div id="outer">
  outer
  <div id="inner">inner</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Oh! The center of the box! How come I didn't think about it. That explained why limiting the width of the box will bring the text back onto the page. And that also explained why raising margin-left of body will pull `inner` back under the `outer` because raising margin will lead to narrow width which in turn makes text and the center closer. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```css
div#inner {
            transform: rotate(30deg) translate(20px) perspective(30px);
   width: 100px;
        }
```

```html
<div id="outer">
        outer
        <div id="inner">inner</div>
    </div>
```

Comment: The order of transformation list is critical and I was trying to do some 3D transformation. Not 2D.

Comment: @krave try transform: perspective(500px) translate3d(10px,20px,20px);